# Show that $\frac{dP}{d\nu} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \frac{d P_n}{d \nu}$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Let $P=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n P_n$ be a probability measure where $a_n >0$, $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of probability measures and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=1$. If $P \ll \nu$ where $\nu$ is a sigma-finite measure, is it possible to show that $\frac{dP}{d\nu} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \frac{d P_n}{d \nu}$ ?

I know that by the Radon–Nikodym theorem, the last statement is true for a finite sum but I am not really sure how to prove this infinite sum.

Comment: $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ tip: Use `\ll` to get the proper symbol for "is absolutely continuous w.r.t."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just be the monotone convergence theorem.  If $\{\mu_n\}$ is a sequence of $\sigma$-finite measures, $\mu = \sum_n \mu_n$, and $\mu \ll \nu$ for some $\sigma$-finite measure $\nu$, then $\mu_n \ll \nu$ and all $n$ and for any measurable set $E$ you have
$$\int_E \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\, d\nu = \mu(E) = \sum_n \mu_n(E) = \sum_n \int_E \frac{d\mu_n}{d\nu} d\nu = \int_E \sum_n \frac{d\mu_n}{d\nu} \, d\nu$$ because $d\mu_n/d\mu \ge 0$ for all $n$.

Since $E$ is arbitrary it follows that $$\frac{d\mu}{d\nu} = \sum_n \frac{d\mu_n}{d\nu}$$$\nu$-almost everywhere.

Comment: Ohh! I didn't notice that MCT solves it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It will be quite helpful if you see this as well : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4277082/use-radon-nikodym-theorem-to-find-the-pdf